# Git comparing two files

Tags: git

I want to compare the file on my Github folder on my RPi with the one on the repository, to check which modification to keep.

Then I did:

```
git diff file.ext
```

But I don't understand which file is which :

```
diff --git a/file.ext b/file.ext
```

I found that `a` is the source file, and `b` the destination one. But from what point of view?
Which is the file on my RPi, and which is the one on the GitHub rep?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The changes in the file `a/file.ext` are represented by `---`. For the file `b/file.ext` the changes are visualised with `+++`. Thus the source file is the remote file and the destination file is your local changed file.

[image: git diff bash]

You can also test it for yourself by comparing the remote file with the local file. Then you can have another look at `git diff`. A more detailed description of the `git diff` command can be found [here](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/ebook/en/command-line/advanced-topics/diffs/).